# Transparent application load-balancer

Tags: spring, docker, proxy

I have a series of Spring application communicating between each other over REST. Each application is wrapped inside a docker container. My objective is to have transparent client load-balancing, that also supports hot-swap of IP addresses.

I'm aware of projects such as Ribbon - but I don't see why the Java application should be responsible for that.

A local TCP/HTTP proxy (haproxy) could do the job, and it could be embedded within each container, running next to each Spring application. Another option would be to have one proxy per server, but then it would add one more layer of complexity - as 1 more container is required.

So, here are the questions:

1. Is there any advantage of having a client-side load balancer embedded within the application?
2. Would having multiple proxies on the same server cause an excessive performance impact, compared to having a single one per server?

Comment: How are you deploying your application containers?

Comment: As of now, standard docker run, planning to use swarm mode